# Vuforia virtual buttons in Cloud Recognition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Is there a way to add virtual buttons to a cloud recognition app? [There's a post on the internet](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/virtual-button-not-working-unity-android) that virtual buttons are not working in cloud recognition mode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "There's a post on the internet" <-- Please add a link to your question. Also be as specific as possible. To me it's not clear what "virtual button"
and "cloud recognition app" are.

Comment: @Neolisk https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/virtual-button-not-working-unity-android

Comment: An answer has been given. Looks legit. Mark it correct and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the Moderator from Qualcomm itself:

> Cloud Reco Targets do not support Virtual Buttons, as indicated in the
>   dev guide:
>
> https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/virtual-buttons

An alternative would be to use on-screen buttons instead.